# Why does one property work and the other not?

Tags: python-3.x

It happens that I have two property implementations. but one works and the other does not. That is, that in one it does not even enter the setters.

I gave myself the task of wandering online, and this happens to me is very rare, both are supposed to work.

Do you know why this happens?

Thank you

```
class QuickTasks():

    def __init__(self, name=None, value=None):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            self._name = value
        else:
            raise TypeError("name must be str")

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            self._value = value
        else:
            raise TypeError("value must be int")

obj = QuickTasks(name=4, value='j')
print(obj.name)
obj.name = 5
print(obj.name)

################################################################

class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.value = value
        self._left_node = None
        self._right_node = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            self._value = 8
        else:
            raise TypeError("value must be int")

def main():
    tree_node = TreeNode(3)
    #tree_node.value = 3
    print (tree_node.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("")
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you doing `if type(value).__name__ == "int":`, instead of either `isinstance(value, int)` or `type(value) is int`?

Comment: @ShadowRangerm, I know it's better to use isinstance (), but leave it because it's the one that works. I thought that had to do with it. but it is true, it is better isinstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the line:

```
obj = QuickTasks(name=4, value='j')
```

and it assigns to `self.name` in the `QuickTasks` initializer, it raises a `TypeError`, which you don't catch. That bypasses the rest of your code entirely, skipping all uses of the `value` property (and of `TreeNode` entirely).

Comment: I catch the error (the one you say is generated in self.name), but the TreeNode still works (does not stop) and does not mark any errors even if it is inside a try / except block

Comment: @Retr0: Why should it? It demands an `int`, and you give it an `int`. Seems to `print` the `8` as expected: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFNbsMgEIX3nAK5i2CpysabKpKlniCr7EduMm6oCCCYVPLpXf6M7ahsQHwz770BO9Hd6G6e2VUN3vOLQzybGwrz9YNXak@Mh3XDkQNILQlAeFTjO/8d1BN5z89GY6mKK8LjwtK@R6BwJNDBofS@YCe/73ueCj6tMxYdTTVO0k5ZNu4O6el0kYJsn/vT@eiRCN0/GmWejZQcOU0WRb4Panp4IADve95ITc1auYaHZfCPClF53JdaF9pFo1E1LWMxxmOQWhRrCu@/jF//omsTe6uwvnDHqiQXLzioy/hta/ADQPQCOJzYJkqT5XOMef4D "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: I meant the QuickTasks class, that doesn't work for me even with changes

Comment: Put the class that does not work for me, in your online interpreter, and it works, but on my PC, it does not work the same, according to your experience. Is this due to the version of my interpreter?

Comment: https://imgur.com/BBOlskU.png (This does my PC)
https://imgur.com/YPMkEjx.png (This makes me an online interpreter)

Comment: @Retr0: Are you using Python 2 locally? You should upgrade to Python 3. If you absolutely can't for some reason, change the class declarations to explicitly inherit from `object`, to make them new-style (e.g. `class QuickTasks(object):`, as `property` requires new-style classes to work. Python 3 classes are always new-style, Python 2 defaults to old-style (which are generally worse).

Comment: It happens that in Linux, there are both versions (2 and 3), I am going to try each of their recommendations to see if this madness of my interpreter stops. Have a great day and thanks.

Comment: Solved I had to run the file directly from the terminal with version 3. You were absolutely right. Vscode was having trouble choosing the interpreter apparently, I guess having 2 locally.